# How to assign enclosed variable at lefthand side in Python?

Tags: python, closures

Is it possible to assign enclosed variable from within closure in Python?

```
v = "mytext"

def f():
  v = "newtext"

f()

print v
```

I would like it to print "newtext"

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a global variable:

```
def f():
    global v
    v = "newtext"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `global v` inside your method:

```
v = "mytext"

def f():
  global v
  v = "newtext"

f()

print(v)
```

Output:

```
 newtext
```